# Next.js 13 How to pass data from middleware to components

Tags: next.js13, next.js14

I want to pass data from next.js middleware to components,  I do not want to set headers or cookies as it a JSON data and it does not feel right to pass the JSON data in header or cookie. Is there any other way?